# Directus API SDK: How to get items with M2M filter

Tags: javascript, php, directus

I can't find (even in the docs) the best way to do an API call with M2M, from sdk-js. For example, if I have two collections "articles" and "categories" with an M2M relation. How do I get all the articles from one categorie_id ?

I've tried this :

```
directusClient.getItems(
  'articles',
   {
     filter: {
       categories: {
         id: req.params.id
       } 
     }
   }
)
```

But I get this error : 
`Error: Unknown filter: id at new APIError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found my error.. I just had to use `filters` instead of `filter`.
Thus, I had to use the attribute `categories_id` instead of `id`.

Final code :

```
directusClient.getItems(
 'articles',
 {
   filters: {
     categories: {
       categories_id: req.params.id
     }
   }
 } 
)
```